# Does every set have choice sequences as long as the original set?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

> Given a set $X$, we say that $X$ has *choice sequences of length $|I|$*, denoted $CS(|X|,|I|)$, if for any $f:I\to{\cal P}(X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ there is a function $g:I\to X$ such that $g(x)\in f(x)$ for all $x\in I$.

The notion of choice sequence is closely related to $AC_\kappa$, which asserts $\forall{\frak n},CS({\frak n},\kappa)$. It is easy to show

- $\forall n<\omega,CS({\frak m},n)$
- ${\frak m\le \frak n}\land{\frak p\le \frak r}\to CS({\frak n,r})\to CS({\frak m,p})$ (this also shows that $CS(|X|,|I|)$ does not depend on $X$ or $I$ individually but only their cardinals)
- $\forall{\frak m},CS({\frak n,m})\iff CS({\frak n},2^{\frak n})\iff\frak n$ is an aleph

My question concerns the status of $\forall{\frak n},CS({\frak n,n})$. My guess is that it is consistently false in $ZF$, but I haven't been able to find a counterexample. The obvious starting point is $CS(|X|,|X|)$ where $X=\bigsqcup_{n<\omega}2$ is a countable disjoint union of pairs with no choice function. Clearly for this set we have $\lnot\,CS(|X|,\omega)$, but since $\omega\not\le |X|$ I can't apply the first property above to immediately conclude, and most of the test functions on $X$ I can think of already break the pair symmetry in such a way that you can reconstruct a choice function. Does this counterexample work?

Comment: You can write $\mathsf{AC}_\mathfrak p(X)$ to denote that every collection of size $\frak p$ of non-empty subsets of $X$ admits a choice function. This also has a notation using the $\mathbf{C}(x,y,z)$ which I am not a huge fan of.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's the third parameter in the $\mathbf C$ notation? I read about the various parameterized versions of $AC$ a while ago but Wikipedia failed me looking it up now so I made up my own notation.

Comment: Size of the family, size of the sets in the family, and the third parameters is, I supposed less used or moved to sub/super-script as a limiting set. Open one of the papers by Howard/Herrlich/Keremedis/Tachtsis that deal directly with various choice functions admission principles. They use it often, and I might be remembering wrong the notation or the order of the parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement is in fact equivalent to the axiom of choice.

Suppose that the axiom of choice fails, and let $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$ be a family of non-empty sets not admitting a choice function. Take $X=\bigcup A_i\cup I$.

Now fix some $i_0\in I$ and consider the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}A_i& x=i\\ A_{i_0}& x\notin I\end{cases}$, if this admitted a choice function, then the restriction to $I$ will be a choice function from $\{A_i\mid i\in I\}$.

Comment: FWIW there is also a way to combine the given properties to get the statement without explicitly describing choice functions: For any $\frak n$, ${\frak n}\le2^{\frak n}$ implies $CS(2^{\frak n},2^{\frak n})\to CS({\frak n},2^{\frak n})$; the left side is the assumption and the right side implies $\frak n$ is an aleph, so the well-ordering theorem is true